# pygal: How to show the data labels in the saved png

Tags: python, pygal

If I include `label` as in the code snippet below, it shows the data labels when rendered as svg and mouse-hover. However, how do I make the labels show up in a saved png?

```
import pygal

chart = pygal.XY()
chart.add('line A', [{'value': (10, 2), 'label': 'A0'}, {'value': (15, 20), 'label': 'A1'}])

chart.render_to_file('chart.svg')  # this shows the labels on mouse hover
chart.render_to_png('chart.png')  # how do I make this to show the data labels?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`print_lables=True`](https://www.pygal.org/en/3.0.0/documentation/configuration/data.html#print-labels) option when initializing your `pygal` graph for the labels to be displayed in the `png`:

```
chart = pygal.XY(print_labels=True)
```